# Select Count with trimmed rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL DB table, where I store part status journal, ie. how a HW part has changed somewhere.

I need to get exactly one row (ordered by date) for every part and then count all rows, where `new_status` is equal to 2.

Now to put it in example, I came up with this query:

```sql
Select part_sys_id, old_status, new_status, sys_created 
From Vhw_status_journal 
Where i = 5 
Order by sys_created desc
```

Which gets me (note that `i` is just an internal column):

```
part_sys_id | old_status | new_status | sys_created
-----------------------------------------------------------
     21     |     2      |     3      | 2015-08-19 11:00:25
     21     |    NULL    |     2      | 2015-08-19 10:59:28
     20     |     1      |     2      | 2015-08-18 14:13:04
     20     |     2      |     1      | 2015-08-17 10:51:03
     20     |    NULL    |     2      | 2015-08-12 15:05:46
```

Now it turns out that I am completely lost when I have to get only the newest entry for each part_sys_id (I tried `Select Disctint` to no avail) and then even count the output rows where new_status = 2.

My requested output is:

```
part_sys_id | old_status | new_status | sys_created
-----------------------------------------------------------
     21     |     2      |     3      | 2015-08-19 11:00:25
     20     |     1      |     2      | 2015-08-18 14:13:04
```

And then I need to count the rows with new_status = 2, ie. I should then get something like:

```
count
-----
  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 with cte
    as
    (
    select row_number() over(partition by part_sys_id order by sys_created desc) as ri,part_sys_id, old_status, new_status, sys_created
    from Vhw_status_journal
    where i = 5
    )

    select count(*) from cte where ri=1 and new_status=2
```

Comment: Hi, that gives me `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.` :(

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek : try now

Comment: Now it works, but it returns only one row with max part_sys_id.

Comment: Thanks, but now it displays all parts where in any point in time there was new_status = 2, which is not what I want. :\

Comment: I edited my question to show better what output I need. :)

Comment: I updated answer. it should give you first output you are expecting. Are you expecting second output too in one go?

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. But I still get only one row (the top one in the original 5 rows long output).

Comment: Now, it should and it will... :)

Comment: It actually does work now! Thanks! :) Would you also know how to count the result now in one query?

Comment: I think I got it. I just replaced the `select * from cte where ri=1` with `select count(*) from cte where ri=1 and new_status=2`. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select part_sys_id, old_status, new_status, max(sys_created )
From Vhw_status_journal Where i = 5 GROUP BY part_sys_id
```

That should give you only one of each part_sys_id, the newest one.

**EDIT: the group by has to be infront of the order by.**

**EDIT2: It was an inproper way to use `order desc, limit 1`  better use `max()`**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! However, it gives me the following error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.`

Comment: Thanks :) Now I get `Column 'Vhw_status_journal.old_status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: SQL is going to kill me some day sooner or later. :)

Answer (score 0):

My colleague gave mi this query, which also works:

```
select count(*) from Vhw_status_journal 
where sys_id = 
  (select max(sys_id)
  from Vhw_status_journal Vhw_status_journal_alias
  where Vhw_status_journal.part_sys_id = Vhw_status_journal_alias.part_sys_id)
and new_status = 2
```